# Mysql: copy certain columns from one row to another

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there an easy way to as an example copy COL2 and COL3 from row with ID3 to row with ID2 and replace any existing value?

```
ID---COL1---COL2---COL3
1.   A        B        C
2.   D        E        F
3.   G        H        I
4.   J        K        L
```

Comment: Why do you don't write a stored procedure where you do something like this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=79f5070439c2d0050d35292452e76977  only you you have as inout row number column for source and destination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UPDATE` with a self-join.

```
UPDATE yourTable AS t1
CROSS JOIN yourTable AS t2
SET t1.col2 = t2.col2, t1.col3 = t2.col3
WHERE t1.id = 2
AND t2.id = 3
```

Comment: An inner join is used when there's a relationship between the rows. There's no relationship here, it's just two specific IDs.

Comment: I think they're treated equivalently, but you could check whether EXPLAIN shows a difference.

Comment: Good point. EXPLAIN is identical, with or without an index on `id`. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very primitive way of updating the desired row. Considering that the table was declared as `tab` in the DB you can actually `JOIN` it with a subquery filtered from the table itself without using an `ON` and then setting your desired variables accordingly.

```
UPDATE  tab JOIN  (SELECT * FROM tab WHERE ID = 3) AS temp SET   tab.COL1 = temp.COL1, tab.COL2 = temp.COL2, tab.COL3 = temp.COL3 WHERE tab.ID = 2
```